# List View in Fragment not working

Tags: android, listview, fragment, android-xml, android-listfragment

Heres my fragment code :

```
public class LeftFragment extends ListFragment {

ArrayList<String> data;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.left_fragment, container, false);

    data = new ArrayList<String>();
    data.add("1. dell");
    data.add("2. samsung");
    data.add("3. apple");
    data.add("4. hp");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

and heres my xml for this fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FF0000" >

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Heres the list :"/>

<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and

```
 logcat file says :Binary XML file line #5:error inflating class fragment !!
```

what my project has is: two fragments left and right.
left one should contain the List View,

but wat i hav observed is fragments are working fine when i Dont use "ListView" in xml !! but as i am using it.. left fragment is occupying the space of right fragment as well.

Please help ! thank you !

Comment: please post another xml file where u are adding fragments left are right. I think your are getting error in that file.

Comment: i can add if yu want but thats not a problem my friend because i tried the whole code just without <ListView> in xml and it was working fine !!

Answer (score 0):

Your error message seems to suggest that the background color is not being read properly. For black try using "#ff000000" or "#ffff0000" for red.

Comment: noh thats working fine i tried it without ListView,,, it was working fine with correct colors...

Comment: If it's always showing that error message then it's likely in one of your other XML file. It's possible they're both okay on their own yet conflict when used together.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.left_fragment, container, false);
}


    @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ArrayList<String> data;  
  data = new ArrayList<String>();
  data.add("1. dell");
  data.add("2. samsung");
  data.add("3. apple");
  data.add("4. hp");

  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
 }
```