# List View in a fragment is not working?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using the following code for using a listview in a fragment. I don't know why it is not working?

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        SharedPreferences allcontactssharedpreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("ALL_LIST_FOR_CONTROL", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        Map<String,?> keys = allcontactssharedpreferences.getAll();

        for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),entry.getKey(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if ( entry.getKey() != null)
                AllContacts.add(entry.getKey());
        }

        listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.theListOfHistoryControl);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,AllContacts);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }
```

I tried the follwing solving, but it didn't work either: [List View in Fragment not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030992/list-view-in-fragment-not-working)

```
  @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        SharedPreferences allcontactssharedpreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("ALL_LIST_FOR_CONTROL", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        Map<String,?> keys = allcontactssharedpreferences.getAll();

        for(Map.Entry<String,?> entry : keys.entrySet()){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),entry.getKey(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            if ( entry.getKey() != null)
                AllContacts.add(entry.getKey());
        }

//        listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.theListOfHistoryControl);
//
//        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,AllContacts);
//
//        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.theListOfHistoryControl);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,AllContacts);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Please help me.

Edit 1:fragment_home.xml is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.shiza.callhistorycontrol.Home">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/theListOfHistoryControl" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/theListOfHistoryControl">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please report your exact problem. What exactly happens when you run this piece of code?

Comment: @Srikrishnan Nothing appears on the screen. Except a text view from xml. The list view is not loaded except everything is workin fine.

Comment: Have you make sure datas are in there in The AllContacts?

Comment: Toast.makeText(getActivity(),entry.getKey(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); gives me data, and I add it to the array.

Comment: Post your R.layout.fragment_home.

Comment: Can you add your activity that holds the fragment?

Comment: @kodingralph I solve the issue. It was : <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/theListOfHistoryControl" />