# ArrayAdapter not binding data to ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I am trying learn Android and building a very basic ListView, the data set up using ArrayAdapter is not showing up. My `Activity` code is:

**MainActivity Class(default no changes)**

```
`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}`


**MainActivityFragment class**

    public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private ListAdapter arrayAdapter;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ArrayList<String> myEntries = new ArrayList<String>();
        myEntries.add("Unix");
        myEntries.add("Java");
        myEntries.add("Android");

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast, R.id.list_forecast_item_textview, myEntries);


        ListView listView = (ListView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false).findViewById(R.id.list_view_forecast);

listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }
}
```

**list_item_forecast.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:minHeight="?android:listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/list_forecast_item_textview">

</TextView>
```

**fragment_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivityFragment"
    android:id="@+id/forecastFragment">


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_view_forecast" />

    <include layout="@layout/list_item_forecast" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"         android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

All my application code is as above.  I have tried tweaking the code and also tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18030992/list-view-in-fragment-not-working) but cannot get this to work. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `listview` you `setAdapter` is not the `listview` you return in the `fragment`.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ArrayList<String> myEntries = new ArrayList<String>();
        myEntries.add("Unix");
        myEntries.add("Java");
        myEntries.add("Android");

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_forecast, R.id.list_forecast_item_textview, myEntries);

View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        ListView listView = (ListView)view .findViewById(R.id.list_view_forecast);

listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        return view ;
    }
```

Comment: Better if you add some explanation to answer by which user know why current snippet not working

Comment: thank you Tiny Sunlight, it worked. As I understand this was soemthing related to java concept of objects, if you could please also explain what was wrong here, that would be helpful.

Comment: Ok I think the issue was not returning the View object on which setAdapter was being used.

Comment: fragment will show view onCreateView return.you inflate a view and find listview in it  and setAdapter. but you haven't return it  onCreateView . you inflate a new and return.